# Non blocking system call and mode switch

Tags: linux, kernel, io, system-calls

Suppose we invoke a system call for asynchronous IO. At the time of invoking system call, the mode changes from user mode to kernel mode . After invocation, the mode should immediately change back to user mode so that user application can proceed further(as it is non blocking).

Now if the mode is changed to user mode then how will kernel proceed with IO as mode is changed from kernel to user mode ? Will kernel perform asynchronous IO in user mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Processes that want to use AIO, creates AIO context (kioctx) through io_setup(). AIO context has a ring buffer (aio_ring_info). This memory buffer will be in the address space of the process but accessible to the kernel.